# How to save 2 image per frame?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm very noob, i don't know how to save 2 diferent image for the same render animation to save time.

i want to save this both image per frame automatically:

[image: depthmap]

[image: normal]

like: frame1_0.png & frame1_1.png, frame2_0.png & frame2_1.png etc...

Comment: You can add multiply File Output node in the Compositor Editor. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using compositor you can easily output passes you want.

[image]

[image]